# After Bamboo CI runs it's indicating build job is success even though some of the Cypress tests are failing

Tags: cypress, bamboo

Running Cypress tests in Bamboo.Bamboo build job is showing success with green mark even though Cypress tests has some failure tests.

I expect, if cypress test has some failure then Bamboo build status indicating that build is failed with red cross symbol

Comment: Cypress will exit with a non-zero exit code if the tests failed. Check your CI script and ensure you don't have an `|| true` after your cypress run command in your CI config.

Comment: @bkucera yes, I checked it and it doesn't have || true in CI config.

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo always expects the exit code `exit 0` for the build to pass successfully. Any other exit code value will fail the build.
You may add the below snip at the end of your plan in a [script task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html) based on where your build is running and then the Build log should list the exit code result.

**For Windows based agents:**

```
echo ==========
$LastExitCode
echo ==========
```

**For Linux based agents:**

```
echo ==========
echo $?
echo ==========
```

This should give you an idea on what is being sent back to Bamboo to decide. You may then alter your plan accordingly to produce the right error code.